# LibGdx Texture loading in game and using it for various listeners

Tags: libgdx

hi i am developing a game using libgdx. I want to make the texture object available to entire   application. I have a requirement like, initialize the texture in one application listener and   i want to use it in another application listener. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I think you can do this. First, you could read the data into a static variable. For an example of this, take a look at the Art class in metagun demo: [Art.java](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/demos/metagun/metagun-desktop/src/com/mojang/metagun/Art.java%20Art.java). The second way, which I have not tried yet, is to use the new [AssetManager](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/index.html?com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html) class. There is example use in the [AssetManager test](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/AssetManagerTest.java). These should help you access your textures more easily.

Comment: I didn't get the first way of doing instead i am going for second one

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have 2 or more Application listeners. Actually that only makes things harder.

Use [Screens](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html) instead (extending [Game](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.html) in your core class instead of directly implementing ApplicationListener).

Either way, you should be able to just send the textures as arguments. For example I have a class **Assets** that contains all the textures and I sent it to each screen. You can make them static as Doran suggested too.